# Using polymorphic collection

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a situation like below:

```cpp
    #include <set>
    #include <map>
    #include <vector>
    #include <string>

    class BaseCollection {
        // I don't know what to keep here
        // I want to have access to collection elements
        // seems I need to implmement begin(), end() for collections
    };

    class CollectionA : public BaseCollection {
        public: // in real code this will be private
            std::vector<double> coll_;
    };

    class CollectionB : public BaseCollection {
        public: // in real code this will be private
            std::set<double> coll_;
    };

    class CollectionC : public BaseCollection {
        public: // in real code this will be private
            std::map<std::string, double> coll_;
    };

    class Base {
        public:
            virtual BaseCollection* getColl() = 0;
    };

    class A : public Base {
        virtual BaseCollection* getColl() { return &coll_; }
        public: // in real code this will be private
            CollectionA coll_;
    };

    class B : public Base {
        virtual BaseCollection* getColl() { return &coll_; }
        public: // in real code this will be private
            CollectionB coll_;
    };

    class C : public Base {
        virtual BaseCollection* getColl() { return &coll_; }
        public: // in real code this will be private
            CollectionC coll_;
    };

    class Container {
        public:
        typedef std::map<std::string, Base*>::const_iterator const_iterator;
        Container::const_iterator begin() const { return objects_.begin(); }
        public: // in real code this will be private
            std::map<std::string, Base*> objects_;
    };


    int main() {
        // somewhere we're creating objects of different types and filling their collections
        A objA;
        // suppose we filled objA.coll_ somehow
        Base* ptrA = new A;
        ptrA = &objA;

        // somwhere we're iterationg over Container
        Container c;
        c.objects_["objA"] = ptrA;
        Container::const_iterator itBeg = c.begin();
        BaseCollection* coll = itBeg->second->getColl();
        // and here I want to itarate over collection
}
```

So, I need somehow define at least `begin()`, `end()` for the `BaseCollection` and implement them in derived classes. 
Or maybe I need to use templates? But I couldn't figure that out.
How can I do that?
Or maybe it's not possible, and I need to keep separate containers for each type (`A`, `B`, `C`).

**EDIT:**
So, what I have is a `Base` class, and some classes derived from it (`A`, `B`, `C`) which contain different types of collections. Actually what I want to have is an interface in `Base` to iterate over the collection of derived class on which it is currently pointed to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you shed a bit more light on what your aiming to achieve? Is what you want is a collection of elements, in which all elements are either of type A, type B, or type C? And do you want to be able to access them individually as type A or just as the base type?

Comment: @laurisvr, Yes, elements in collection are either of type A, type B, or type C and I want to be able access them as a base type.

Comment: Do you *have* to use multiple child-classes for the collection? Can't you simply use a single templated `Collection` class and use that in your `A`, `B` and `C` classes? And I don't really see the reason for `A`, `B` and `C` having a common ancestor class either, can you please try to explain the use-case you have? What problem you are actually trying to solve? (you might want to read about [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, if I had a single templated `Collection` class, then my Base class will be templated too, but I want it to be non-template. I'll edit my question and will write the actual problem.

Comment: And iterator has to iterate over a specific list type. So if you want it to be type dependent you'd have to work with class templates. But are you sure this is what you want? Why not create a base type, and create a collection of this? That way the iterator can be of the base type. And you can cast to the type you need.

Comment: @laurisvr, I'm trying to avoid doing casts.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to avoid casts if i may ask? Polymorphism is virtually impossible whilst avoiding casts. And it seems like to problem you have requires either polymorphism, or class templates.

Comment: @laurisvr, as you know, down casting is not recommended (it's a quite slow operation). And, if I'll use use it, I'll break my design, as anytime I need to access collection inside of `Container`, I'll need to do down casting.

Comment: @Heghine In that case, how about a base class, with a void pointer to a class, and a variable specifing the class type. That way you can use traditional (and fast:) )pointer casts. And you avoid both downcasting and templates:). Be sure to delete the type pointed to in your destructor of course:).

Comment: I've answered a question that seems quite similar to yours [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29930911/4326278).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
You could implement a parallel hierarchy of iterators Base iterator class for BaseCollection and one iterator for each derived collection class.
Again, when value type is different among iterators, you could define a common value type as some kind of variant or return everything as string.

It is not trivial. you have to implement in each particular class begin/end and in each derived iterator the value access function, operators like copy/compare etc.

Isn't it easier, to make the base class of your kind of value (not of the collection) and store pointers to the objects in a standard container?

**Original**
Use templates for code reuse

Use polymorphism for providing same interface and hiding the implementation

In your case you use different containers having different types inside the derived classes. Is it only an example, or should it be like that? If the second, templates won't help here.

Implementing begin/end is not a problem e.g. `virtual void begin() =0;` 
The implementation in derived classes should set some private index or iterator pointing at the position in your particular container.

The question is also, which type will you return? A kind of variant could be a solution.

Comment: How could begin() return void? Need to return iterator to a container I think.

Comment: I see. There are interfaces, where begin resets the collection (internal index set to begin of internal container) and getNext returns the next valid value as well as increments the internal index. So it's not what you wanted. Then you should implement a hierarchy or iterators, I think. pls. see the update soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access element's either as base type or as type a, b, or c. polymorphic is the way to go. But you shouldn't be inheriting from the collection. So your base type would look like this:

```
class baseType{
    //define share parameters here like:
    int baseInt;
    //and pure virtual functions like:
    int elementType() = 0;
}
```

And your collection would look like this:

```
class BaseCollection {
    std::list<baseType> baseList;
 };
```

An inheriting type would look like this:

```
 class typeA:baseType{

 //a pure virtual has to be overridden so:
 int elementType() { return 1;}
 }
```

Note that the collection will always return an element of the baseType type. If you'd like to know what the inherited type is. There's two ways of doing this.

- Do a static cast to the pointer of a the baseType, casting to the type you want. This will return null, if the type isn't the desired type.
- Create a (pure) virtual function that returns an integer or other kind of variable, indicating the type. Like done above.

When there is a lot over inheriting types, you might want to do the latter. Since it'd be a lot of static_casts